# How to delete "any" element of a list in elixir

Tags: list, elixir, element

I have a list of lists

```
>> list = [[1,""],[2,"b"],[3,""],[4,"c"]]
```

I want to delete the lists that contains "" element

```
>>list = [[2,"b"],[4,"c"]]
```

I'm trying to find something like

```
list = List.delete(list,[any,""])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could combine [`Enum.reject/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reject/2) with [`Enum.member?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#member?/2) and reject any list that contains empty string

```rb
iex> Enum.reject([[1,""],[2,"b"],[3,""],[4,"c"]], &Enum.member?(&1, ""))
[[2, "b"], [4, "c"]]
```

If your inner lists are always the same two-item style and you're only wanting to check the second item, you could also use an anonymous function

```rb
iex> Enum.reject([[1,""],[2,"b"],[3,""],[4,"c"]], fn [_, b] -> b == "" end)
[[2, "b"], [4, "c"]]
```

or a comprehension that does pretty much the same thing

```rb
iex> for [a, b] when b != "" <- [[1,""],[2,"b"],[3,""],[4,"c"]], do: [a, b]
[[2, "b"], [4, "c"]]
```

Comment: `===` and `!==` are counter-idiomatic here. Use `==` and `!=` instead.

Comment: Also: `Enum.reject([[1,""],[2,"b"],[3,""],[4,"c"]], & match?([_, ""], &1))` and `Enum.reject([[1,""],[2,"b"],[3,""],[4,"c"]], fn [_, ""] -> true; _ -> false end)`.

Comment: I'd never thought to use `match?/2` that way. I love it!

Comment: Well, two examples I posted, result in the absolutely same code. `Kernel.match?/2` gets expanded into [two clauses as above](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.9.1/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L2820).